# How can I pass data to any template from any view in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Like a good little coder, all of my Django templates inherit from a base.html. Now I would like to add some functionality to the base to always show some interesting things. Some user statistics, or random posts, or feeds, etc.

All of my views look like this:

```
def viewname(request) :
    template_vales = {}
    // Stuff
    return render_to_response('some_file_name.html', template_values)
```

How can I make it so that the values of template_values are always populated for all my views? Do I have to do this at the start of all of my views? As in:

```
import utils

def viewname(request) :
    template_values = {}
    utils.addDefaults(template_values)
    // Stuff
    return render_to_response('some_file_name.html', template_values)
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use context processors:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/

In my settings.py, I add a couple of functions to the standard ones (see the last two):

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  "django.core.context_processors.request",
  "django.core.context_processors.auth",
  "django.core.context_processors.debug",
  "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
  "thetrailbehind.context_processors.canonical_url",
  "thetrailbehind.context_processors.gmapkey",)
```

The first one I add defines the canonical URL for the view, and the second switches between GMap keys. Here's that function:

```
def gmapkey(request):
  url = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
  key = ""
  if url == "127.0.0.1:8000":
    key = "ABQIAAAAGFSvsJjnPmsGb7IcfqoamBTpH3CbXHjuCVmaTc5MkkU4wO1RRhTaJZRNQLjBhGtJlm6eE4gJtku-Rw"   
  elif url ==  "192.168.11.3:8000":
    key = "ABQIAAAAGFSvsJjnPmsGb7IcfqoamBTm8-wcGRt2V-0p00qdRdGeyDhtGBSRTbk2s1ciA8vzdxGeAnqq6g-F4g"
  elif url ==  "192.168.11.17:7000":
    key="ABQIAAAAmHGaJpkZhJ6huJ93yfaYERTmT93Y0kqi8UE3J2QowoLz6rHdtxTHqeJ0nRoENl5LY5gCqHhRK9Yasg"
  elif url == "192.168.1.200:8000":
    key="ABQIAAAAmHGaJpkZhJ6huJ93yfaYERR5_sKpsr8Ui4YjC4HGOe8xaUDeVhSxGV1r1rIL1OvmVMAGUQBoUK0H2w"
  elif url == "192.168.1.73:8000":
    key = "ABQIAAAAGFSvsJjnPmsGb7IcfqoamBR7_CRKSBu49YjvDOLq_-DZQHSIYBSip9sO5IHlFIoZMtDpVcduFQCnWg"
  elif url == "www.trailbehind.com":
    key="ABQIAAAAGFSvsJjnPmsGb7IcfqoamBQxFGSDsNggDdRtUnAb8L8sJ910FhSKwoOpNaUlGCQIhyl6Dy5Cbyb0lQ"
  elif url == "dev.trailbehind.com":
    key="ABQIAAAAmHGaJpkZhJ6huJ93yfaYERQzqIbhF_xOwOwM1oDO_kQqYhag7BRsoTInq2lBuE7fsgDN2xfyD2IL5A"
  elif url == "trailbehind.com":
    key = "ABQIAAAAGFSvsJjnPmsGb7IcfqoamBQL9YYTGyB2pLTiscy54DOfsaXeHBQqMBmq7UvWAZVenmRMtNr_bo3TMQ"
  elif url == "tenuki.trailbehind.com":
    key = "ABQIAAAAGFSvsJjnPmsGb7IcfqoamBQ5SkJUKVREyqcvaNQJsRscGi2yVhSj0mJSTasDiWec8Awxb_TUxOdElw"
  elif url == "cabin.trailbehind.com":
    key = "ABQIAAAAmHGaJpkZhJ6huJ93yfaYERSU-76xxg1tvy-8taAiiF1qqcGi1xSmjUhmAs_v2XAuGxKX_Y-4-gDP3Q"
  elif url == "ec2-174-129-167-234.compute-1.amazonaws.com":
    key = "ABQIAAAAmHGaJpkZhJ6huJ93yfaYERStHq7nubctzsNDgkYc34LoSNrRNhQVCNy2KFFm2BT1sG2yrXrw38ycNg"
```

Comment: So I need

from django.template import RequestContext

and 

return render_to_response("my_app/my_template.html", {'some_var': 'foo'},
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))


in every view? I wish the tutorial would have started me down that path. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, here's one of my view functions:

def parks_by_state(request):
  '''a map with polygons for all states'''
  states = EncodedState.objects.all()
  page_title = 'Park Maps By State'
  response_dict = {'states':make_json_states(states), 
                   'page_title':page_title,}     
  return render_to_response("state_map.html", 
                             response_dict, 
                             context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Answer (score 4):

For this I use context processors. For example, if I want get variable `MEDIA_URL` for each view, I define `context_processors.py` like this:

```
def media_url(request):
    from django.conf import settings
    return {'MEDIA_URL': settings.MEDIA_URL}
```

in `settings.py` you must have

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ....
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'myaplication.context_processors.menuitems',
)
```

in view you must have `render_to_response` and `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`
For example:

```
def my_view(request):
return render_to_response('base.html',{},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```