# how to activate DJANGO.CORE.CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.REQUEST

Tags: django, django-templates, django-custom-tags

I read this

> `DJANGO.CORE.CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.REQUEST`
>
> If `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` contains this processor, every
>   RequestContext will contain a variable request, which is the current
>   HttpRequest. Note that this processor is not enabled by default;
>   you'll have to activate it.

from [this page](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/)

But it seems there is no information how to activate this processor.

Here is my original question

[Access request in django custom template tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160261/access-request-in-django-custom-template-tags)

After i followed the answer

i still got errors

```
TemplateSyntaxError at / Caught an exception while rendering: 'request' Original Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 71, in render_node result = node.render(context) 
File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\template__init__.py", line 936, in render dict = func(*args)
 File "c:\...\myapp_extras.py", line 7, in login request = context['request'] 
File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 44, in getitem raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'request'
```

the code causing problem is

**request = context['request']**   in

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('userinfo.html',takes_context = True)
def userinfo(context):
 request = context['request']
 address = request.session['address']
 return {'address':address}
```

Comment: It looks like the fellow trying to help you on the Google Group is being helpful. You should post the code he requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this here: [How can I pass data to any template from any view in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071572/how-can-i-pass-data-to-any-template-from-any-view-in-django/1071594#1071594)

Also see the comments on my answer... you might want that bit of info too.

Comment: thanks , but i already passed "takes_context = True"

and I have     "django.core.context_processors.request" included in settings.py

Why it still get KeyError when i call context['request']

Comment: Why don't you print context (or context.keys()) and see what's in there. Apparently, context doesn't have a "request" key, so see what keys it does have.

Comment: sorry to ask again..

i got this

Exception Value: 
Caught an exception while rendering: 'Context' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: I'm sorry... I thought context was a dictionary, but it's a Context object. What does it output if you just print context?

Comment: thanks a lot Andrew,

It turns out i missed to pass "context_instance=RequestContext(request)" in the view code

Answer (score 2):

in settings.py

```
from django.conf import global_settings

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

Comment: `Note that a settings file should not import from global_settings, because that’s redundant` --> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#default-settings

Comment: That comment is about importing a variable simply to reuse it, which would happen anyway. Here, the code is adding to the default setting from global_settings and so needs to import it in order to have access to it.