# How to check user agent inside Django template?

Tags: python, django, user-agent

I want to check the useragent using Django inside my template. I know this is possible using JavaScript, but I wanted a server side solution.

I know I can use HttpRequest.META in some middleware class, which I am not currently looking for. I want to determine this using some code in the template itself, without any dependency on other files / classes.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use context processors, more specifically `django.core.context_processors.request`.

This SO answer covers it quiet well:
[How can I pass data to any template from any view in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071572/how-can-i-pass-data-to-any-template-from-any-view-in-django/1071594#1071594)

Especially this blog post, that is referenced in the SO answer:

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/